# How to return to a top of a code Python

Tags: python

I have written a code that converts Megabytes to Gigabytes and vice versa the problem is that after the user choses from which unit will he convert he will be prompted to enter the value.I want to print "please enter a word" and return to the top of the code if the user didn't enter anything.Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Show us this code and we can help you

Comment: Use a `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some kind of `loop` structure, i.e. a `for` or `while` loop. However, without your code there isn't anything specific to help with here.

*In fact, as a side-note, any `loop` can also be written using a `recursive function`*

Comment: Your answer is valid, but the question is off-topic, so you should flag it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while True:
    a=input("please enter a word")
    <your code here>
    if a!='':
        break
```

Enter your code that does conversions in  with the variable a.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the optparse module which you can use to output something when using as console program and the user didnt enter the neccessary stuff.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

second option:

```
while True:
    menu_choice = (raw_input("Enter a selection"))
    if menu_choice == 1 | 2:
        break
    else:
        print "This is not a number"

rest_of_code
```

I think that should do.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
    def conv_KB_to_MB(input_kilobyte):
        megabyte = 1./1000
        convert_mb = megabyte * input_kilobyte
        return convert_mb
def conv_MB_to_GB(input_megabyte):
        gigabyte = 1.0/1024
        convert_gb = gigabyte * input_megabyte
        return convert_gb
#Create the menu


print "Enter 1 to convert from KBs to MBs"
print "Enter 2 to convert from MBs to GBs"


try:
        menu_choice = (raw_input("Enter a selection"))
except ValueError:
        print "This is not a number"
except NameError:
        print "Name Error"
except SystenError:
        print "Syntax Error"

if menu_choice == '1':
        kb_input = float(input("Enter KBs"))
        megabytes = conv_KB_to_MB(kb_input)
        print megabytes

elif menu_choice == '2':
        mb_input = float(input("Enter MBs"))
        gigabytes = conv_MB_to_GB(mb_input)
        print gigabytes
else:
        print "exiting"
```